# Unable to mount and failed to install custom ROM in Droid XT912

Tags: rom-flashing, motorola-droid-razr

I have a Droid Razr XT912 which was bricked but now recovered after some effort followed from XDA.

Now I'm trying to install a new custom ROM to my device with Safestrap, but it's giving me a message about failure on every action, such as  failed to create backup, failed on wipe and failed to install.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Can anybody tell me what should I do?